# Android Studio Sync Project with Gradle Files disabled

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I opened up my project today as usual and discovered that my project wasn't synced with Gradle files, and the option to sync project with Gradle files is disabled. This issue has appeared twice now, I don't really know what I did the first time fixed it.

I don't think I've touched any files or settings before this happened.

**Update:** Seems like "Invalidate cache and restart" fixes the problem, but I'd still like to know why this happens? Also, recently this happens almost after every startup of Android Studio, I have to restart every time to make it work.

Comment: care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the second update should stay in the the answer, not the question. See [ask], [answer], and [self-answering](/help/self-answer)

Comment: I updated the question after the downvote, thought that might be the issue. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like "Invalidate cache and restart" fixes the problem, but I'd still like to know why this happens? Also, this happens very often now, basically every day I have to invalidate the cache and restart, it's pretty annoying.

---

**Update**: after updating to Android Studio 3.4, it seems like the problem is gone.

Comment: Faced this issue in 4.1 Preview, tried a bunch of other stuff but this fixed it for me, thanks!